# Wordpress theme - add text arrow if page has subpages

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show an arrow (add text) ">>" behind all the navigation items that have subitems/subpages. Is there a solution with add_filter or do i have to build the menu by myself?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask..
This adds a `class="dropdown"` to your menu's

```
// add a class 'dropdown' to menu items which have a sub menu
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'check_for_submenu', 10, 2);
function check_for_submenu($classes, $item)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='" . $item->ID . "'");
    if ($has_children > 0)
        array_push($classes, 'dropdown'); // add the class dropdown to the current list
    return $classes;
}
```